# Python Pig-Latin translator

Tags: python

```
    import string
def main():
  filename = input("Enter the name of a file to translate into Pig Latin: ")
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','A','E','I','O','U']
  regFile = open((filename), 'r')
  Output = open('Output.txt', 'w')
  for line in  regFile.readlines():
    pigList = line.split()
    t = translate(pigList, vowels)
    w = write(t, Output)
  regFile.close()
  input ("Press ENTER to continue: ")


def translate(pigList, vowels):
  PigList2 = []

  for word in pigList:
    if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
      actual_word = word[:-1]
      ending = word[-1]
    else:
      actual_word = word
      ending = ""

    if word[0] in vowels:
      PigList2.append(actual_word + "-yay" + ending)
    else:
      PigList2.append(actual_word[1:] + "-" + actual_word[0] + "ay" + ending)
  return PigList2

def write(pigList, Output):
  print(" ".join(pigList))

main()
```

I believe this has fixed my errors. Thank you for the help. I know have the translator working correctly and translating all the lines at once instead of one line at a time.

Comment: Can you provide *any* detail as to how your second bit of code is "not working"?

Comment: you are changing the variable `word` in your code, that can be one reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. I just used used the punctuation check to split up your word into the actual word and the punctuation and then append the '-' before the first letter rather than with the "ay".

```
def translate(pigList, vowels):
  PigList2 = []

  for word in pigList:
    if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
      actual_word = word[:-1]
      ending = word[-1]
    else:
      actual_word = word
      ending = ""

    if word[0] in vowels:
      PigList2.append(actual_word + "-yay" + ending)
    else:
      PigList2.append(actual_word[1:] + "-" + actual_word[0] + "ay" + ending)

  return PigList2
```

Comment: Okay I got that to work, thank you! But it is only translating 1 line of the text document. How do I get it to read and translate ALL of the lines?

Comment: Your code is translating all of the lines for me. It's not printing anything to the output file, but you haven't coded that and it asks you to press enter after each line, but once I do that it continues.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I fixed that, new code is at the top.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to edit your question with the answers you've been given. The aim of this site is to help people and if someone came looking at this with a similar problem, it wouldn't make sense to them what was going on. If an answer solved your problem, you can 'accept' it as the answer by pressing the tick next to it which tells people were to look for the answer.